# s.replace within a for loop behaves strangely

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I wrote this to replace all 'b's within 'babble' except for the first one.

```
s = 'babble'
for i in range(1, len(s)):
     if s[i] == s[0]:
         t = s.replace(s[i],'$')
print(t)
```

this prints '$a$$le' instead of 'ba$$le'. 
Why is that?

Comment: Why do you expect it to print 'ba$$le

Comment: Aha, now I get your misunderstanding. You can't pass an index to `replace()` for the whole string, instead it will replace everything in the string all at once. Try printing `t` after `t = s.replace(s[i],'$')`, you will see that the full replacement is done after the first iteration, subsequent iterations just keep printing the same thing.

Comment: This is helpful. I misunderstood usage of s.replace. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str.replace doesn't work the way you think. If you see the documentation It says

`string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`

> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the
>   first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

If you do not want to replace the first character then use slicing rather than for loop i.e

```
s = 'babble'
s = s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0],'$')
```

Output: `ba$$le`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go:

```
s = 'babble'
t = s[0]
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] == s[0]:
        t += '$'
    else:
        t += s[i]
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
ba$$le
```